# How to show page only after executing Java codes in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

The `index.jsp` contains java codes which will fetch some images and texts from a database.

In the JavaScript file I wrote.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //When Document is Ready, Show the Main Page
    $("#showifjavaenabled").fadeIn(1000);

    });
```

So in the beginning, the `DIV showifjavaenabled` is hidden, but I noticed that even when it shows up after 1 second, not all java are executed because they are actually a lot, the time they need to load isn't big, it's only a second or two, but still it's looking bad, how can I `.show() or .fadeIn()` this page only after all java codes have been executed?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question, as @Andrea has said, JSP code should be server side so that `$(document).ready()` will be called at the correct time.

Comment: The question is that he's querying the database from the JSP, 
then from Client and without using an EJB.
I did that too ten years ago, before discovering Struts and EJBs, and i remember this kind of problems. This is an antipattern, do not put business on frontend, and for sake do not put it in client side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons for not putting java code into JSPs...

If you are doing server-side business, you should do it server side, then forward the request to the JSP with all data already loaded.

OR you can use AJAX calls to perform Java frontend operations, using kind of tiles (the page is loaded, the little box loading with ajax has still the progress bar running until he's done.

Avoid scriptlets (`<% %>`)  as much as you can, and separate concepts for a better results.

---

EDIT: 
You should really try to start with some framework like Struts2 (not Struts1, that is harder and less powerful).

It's not difficult, well documented, and the time you spend to learn the 'hello world' and to setup your application will come back immediately in terms of power and easyness, and you could use it for future applications.

Posting a gigantic comma separated string from server to client, and then de-tokenize it there is not Object Oriented Programming.

OOP would be one object for every conceptual object you need to work with, exposed to the JSP through an Action, and accessed in JSP with EL or OGNL tags...

i know the step seems huge, but it is worth doing...

Or you can stay with your antipattern, antediluvian technology and try to hack this problem, maybe for today you will end this software, but tomorrow you will have the same problems.

My 2 cents (as said, i was in your situation years ago... )

Comment: When I'm gonna use AJAX calls to bring some information to put in a dynamic page, I have a problem because I need to .append() lots of stuff, the AJAX calls won't bring me the same amount of information all the time, I know this is all about an approach, and I'm facing problems with the scriplets approach as well, when I use $.get, and I'm not really an expert in it, it returns me a String called responseText from a Servlet, so It's only 1 String which will contains lots of information separated by a comma then I have to separate them in JavaScript <- wrong but I don't know another way :(