# How do I display the results of an aws dynamodb query as soon as a .jsp page loads?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a .jsp page that I am working on. As soon as the page loads, I need to display a javascript alert popup. This popup needs to have the results of a query from an AWS dynamoDB. How can I achieve this if I can only use the Java AWS SDK? (Not the javascript aws sdk) Is this not possible to do because the java is executed on the server while the javascript is executed on the client side?

Comment: How do you load the data? Is the Java code included in the your JSP page or is it some asynchronous call to a server side java bean? Maybe take look at this SO question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083335/how-to-show-page-only-after-executing-java-codes-in-jsp

Comment: Java code is included in the .jsp page

Comment: I would recommend removing the code from the JSP page and putting in somewhere else (in a bean). It is not a good practice and it is going to cause problems later.